# ¿Cómo registrar un control cuando me dice que no es un control extensor registrado?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cuando intento configurar un control `Multiview` para que inicie un view acorde a ciertas características:

```
MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewWeek11);
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> El control extensor `'CalendarExtender_Date'` no es un control extensor
>   registrado. Los controles extensores deben registrarse mediante
>   `RegisterExtenderControl()` antes de llamar a `RegisterScriptDescriptors()`

Dentro de mi `Multiview`, hay estos extensores `AjaxControlKit`. He investigado y me comentan que debo registrar estos controles en:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Pero por más que leo no alcanzo a entender cómo se debe de hacer esto, me podrían dar un ejemplo de como registrar un control de estos dentro de la funcion `OnPreRender`?